# postgres - where in (list) - column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I'm coming from SQL Server and I was suprised to see that the following query does not work:

```
DELETE FROM user_job_titles WHERE id IN (
"c836d018-1d12-4507-a268-a4d80d6d3f54",
"d0961a90-7d31-4c4c-9c1b-671115e3d833",
"62dda420-6e62-4017-b41d-205c0aa82ead"
)
```

where user_job_titles has the following columns:

```
id
user_id
job_title_id
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  column "c836d018-1d12-4507-a268-a4d80d6d3f54" does not exist
LINE 2: "c836d018-1d12-4507-a268-a4d80d6d3f54"
```

I'm using pgAdmin with latest postgresql version. Is there any other way to run this query?

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for string constants: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 15):

Use single quotes for string constants:

```
DELETE FROM user_job_titles
    WHERE id IN ('c836d018-1d12-4507-a268-a4d80d6d3f54',
                 'd0961a90-7d31-4c4c-9c1b-671115e3d833',
                 '62dda420-6e62-4017-b41d-205c0aa82ead'
                );
```

Double quotes are an escape character used with table and column names.  Hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote string literals with `'`

```
DELETE FROM user_job_titles 
WHERE id IN (
'c836d018-1d12-4507-a268-a4d80d6d3f54',
'd0961a90-7d31-4c4c-9c1b-671115e3d833',
'62dda420-6e62-4017-b41d-205c0aa82ead'
);
```

---

> *I'm coming from SQL Server and I was suprised to see that the following query does not work*

Then you have [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) AS `OFF`. By default it is `ON`.

> When **SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON**, all strings delimited by **double
>   quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers**.

Check:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
SELECT "A"


-- The same behaviour as in Postgresql
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SELECT "A"
-- Invalid column name 'A'.
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445882)**</kbd>